# 2D Vectors/Dynamic Arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, vector

I'm trying to work with 2D arrays in order to keep track of some objects that are laid out in a grid fashion. I would like each element of the of the 2d array to contain an `Object*`. `Object` being a class I have defined. However working with these things isn't exactly easy.

This is the my method for filling the 2D array with `Object` pointers:

```
int xDim; 
//how far to go in the x direction
//x's Dimension that is

Object *** test; //the highest level pointer used

test = new  Object ** [xDim];
//add horizontal array of Object **

for(int fillPos=0; fillPos < xDim; fillPos++){
    //point each Object ** to  a new Object * array 
    //add column arrays
    test[fillPos] = new Object*[zDim];
}
```

My intention is then to use this array's `Object` pointers to point to the child class of `Object`, say `childObj`. My intent is to use them in this way.

```
for (int xPos=0; xPos < xDim; xPos++){
    for(int zPos=0; zPos < zDim; zPos++){
        //pointing each Object * in the 2D array to
        //a new childObj
        test[xPos] [zPos] = new childObj;
    }
}
```

I realize this could potentially be a real hassle in terms of memory. I'm asking if this is a nice way to handle such a situation. Could perhaps something like 
`vector< <vector<Object*> >` work better? Would vectors manage the deletion nicely so as to avoid memory leaks? Or perhaps I would simply have to loop through the vector and call `delete` on each `Object*` before getting rid of the vectors themselves?

So, should I use arrays as I have or vectors? What could be some problems associated with each method?

Comment: Use smart pointers with a 2D vector.

Comment: `vector< <vector<Object*> >` would not be much better, but a `vector< <vector<Object> >` probably would, especially if your `Object` is lightweight.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I would like to use the array to not only point to a single child class but multiple different child classes in the same array. This is the reason for my preference in using pointers instead of the Object class itself.

Comment: @Cerin Then you should go with smart pointers as Chris recommended.

Comment: C++11 has smart pointer classes, or if you're with C++03, prefer boost over `auto_ptr`.

Comment: Just in case you don't know about boost's multi_array... http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html

Comment: Or use boost ptr_vector.

Comment: I have just decided on using vectors as they do make things cleaner than dynamic arrays and I was getting some awful memory leaks with arrays. However, I hear from some other people that using smart pointers or boost things are overkill in this situation. It seems to work fairly easily with vectors. But thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `Object ***` requires that you go through and delete each `Object Pointer`, each `Array of Object Pointers`, and then the finally delete the outermost `Array of Object**`, in that order. In my opinion this leaves a lot of room for carelessness and mistakes.

```c++
for (int xPos=0; xPos < xDim; xPos++) {
    for (int zPos=0; zPos < zDim; zPos++) {
        delete test[xPos][yPos];  // delete the object ptr
    }
    delete[] test[xPos];          // delete each array of object ptr
}
delete[] test;                    // delete the array of array of object ptrs
```

I would much rather prefer the vector approach, because the vectors are locally scoped. Dynamic allocation can be rather expensive and should be avoided if possible.

So for the vector approach, you would only need to delete the Object ptrs. (A good rule of thumb is that every call to new requires a corresponding call to delete).

```
vector<vector<Object*>> matrix;

... // some code here

for each (vector<Object*> vec in matrix)
    for each (Object* oPtr in vec)
        delete oPtr;
```

If you knew the size of your 2-D array at compile-time, you could achieve the same effect of avoiding memory management for the 2-D array, and simply manage the Object pointers.

```
Object * matrix[xDim][yDim];  // xDim and yDim are compile-time constants
```

But I still like vectors because they have the added benefit of being able to resize themselves dynamically unlike arrays, so you won't have to worry about knowing the size upfront.